# Producer / Consumer Problem : Facing deadlock

Tags: c#, multithreading, task-parallel-library, producer-consumer

I employed exactly a couple of threads to produce and consume the data within the buffer.
There is only one thread for producing the data and only one thread to consume.

However, I still face deadlock most of the time in the consumer thread while it waits for the producer to finish off its processing. On the other hand, the producer already quit while it has finished its work.

I tested and took a few bytes as input for a file which should be generated as data by the data consumer thread.

Below is the source code.

```
public class FileGenerator
{
    private static readonly string _fileLocation = Path.Combine("Resources", "files");

    private static Faker<Employee> _employeeGenerator = null!;

    private static Random _random = new Random(1);

    private long _maxBufferSize = 28;
    private long _maxFileSizeInBytes = 0;
    private long _totalBytesWritten = 0;

    private Queue<byte[]> _buffer = null;
    private bool _continueProducingData = false;
    static object bufferLock = new object();

    public FileGenerator()
    {
        _buffer = new Queue<byte[]>();
        _continueProducingData = true;

        _employeeGenerator = new Faker<Employee>()
            .RuleFor(e => e.RandomNumberDelimator, 100)
            .RuleFor(e => e.AboutMe, f => f.Lorem.Paragraph(1));
    }

    public void Execute ()
    {
        _maxFileSizeInBytes = fileSize * Convert.ToInt64(100);
        var filename = $"unsorted.{fileSize}.txt";
        var path = string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(location) ? Path.Combine(_fileLocation, filename) : Path.Combine(location, filename);            

        var producerTask = Task.Run(() => GenerateTestDataSetAsyncInternal());
        var consumerTask = Task.Run(() => ConsumeTestDataSetAsync(new StreamWriter(File.Open(path,FileMode.Create), bufferSize : 65535)));

        await Task.WhenAll(producerTask, consumerTask);
    }

    private void GenerateTestDataSetAsyncInternal()
    {
        while (_totalBytesWritten <= _maxFileSizeInBytes)
        {
            _continueProducingData = true;

            lock (bufferLock)
            {
                if (_buffer.Count == 0)
                {
                    long noOfbytesWrittenPerDataBytes = 0;

                    while (noOfbytesWrittenPerDataBytes <= _maxBufferSize)
                    {
                        var dataBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(_employeeGenerator.Generate().ToString());
                        noOfbytesWrittenPerDataBytes += dataBytes.Length;
                        _buffer.Enqueue(dataBytes);
                    }

                    _totalBytesWritten += noOfbytesWrittenPerDataBytes;

                    Monitor.Pulse(bufferLock);
                }
                else
                {
                    Monitor.Wait(bufferLock);
                }
            }
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Producer finished...");

        _continueProducingData = false;
    }

    private void ConsumeTestDataSetAsync(StreamWriter writer)
    {
        while (_continueProducingData)
        {
            lock (bufferLock)
            {
                if (_buffer.Count == 0)
                {
                    Monitor.Wait(bufferLock); --> Here it waits and thinks that the producer is producing and will eventually call Monitor.Pulse, while the producer already finished off.
                    continue;
                }

                while (_buffer.Count != 0)
                {
                    var dataBytes = _buffer.Dequeue();
                    writer.BaseStream.Write(dataBytes, 0, dataBytes.Length);
                    writer.Flush();                            
                }

                Monitor.PulseAll(bufferLock);                    
            }
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Consumer finished...");
    }
}
```

Am I doing something wrong? Is it the right way to implement Producer/Consumer by just considering only 2 threads (one for writing and the other for reading)?

Comment: Coordinating the "done" state between the producer and consumer requires careful program design. It is easy to program a consumer to ignore the possibility that the producer is done, forcing the consumer to deadlock. Consider what conditions the consumer must identify when the producer is done and the shared buffer is empty.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. But how to correct the above code.? Should I completely avoid flags and locks and rely altogether on the Dataflow pattern? or the above code can be corrected?

Comment: I just want to write a 50GB file with random data. For this, I ended up using the producer/consumer pattern by researching almost all possibilities. So this comes to my mind that only 2 threads in chunks can read-write the data so to avoid locks and sequentially on the other hand

Comment: One way to properly shut down the consumer is to add a second data field to the buffer indicating whether or not the producer has completed its work. The producer will set the "complete" flag just before terminating and the consumer will quit when the buffer is empty and the producer-complete flag is set.

Comment: This problem occurs across programming languages and is not specific to C++.

Comment: Is this a learning exercise, or you are building an actual system for production? As an exercise it's OK, but for production you should use tested components (`BlockingCollection<T>`) instead of reinventing the wheel.

Answer (score -2):

Following is a simple producer-consumer example written using Ada. This example demonstrates a solution to coordinating the termination of the producer and consumer without deadlock.

```ada
-- single producer / single consumer with coordinated termination

with Ada.Text_IO; use Ada.Text_IO;

procedure Main is

   -- The shared buffer interface specification
   type idx_t is mod 10;
   type bounded_buffer is array (idx_t) of Integer;
   protected buffer is
      entry write (value : in Integer);
      entry read (value : out Integer);
      procedure proc_set_done;
      function is_empty return Boolean;
      function proc_complete return Boolean;
   private
      Buff        : bounded_buffer;
      Write_Index : idx_t   := idx_t'First;
      Read_Index  : idx_t   := idx_t'First;
      Count       : Natural := 0;
      Complete    : Boolean := False;
   end buffer;

   -- Define the behavior of bounded_buffer
   protected body buffer is
      entry write (value : in Integer) when Count < Buff'Length is
      begin
         Buff (Write_Index) := value;
         Write_Index        := Write_Index + 1;
         Count              := Count + 1;
      end write;

      entry read (value : out Integer) when Count > 0 is
      begin
         value      := Buff (Read_Index);
         Read_Index := Read_Index + 1;
         Count      := Count - 1;
      end read;

      procedure proc_set_done is
      begin
         Complete := True;
      end proc_set_done;

      function is_empty return Boolean is
      begin
         return Count = 0;
      end is_empty;

      function proc_complete return Boolean is
      begin
         return Complete;
      end proc_complete;
   end buffer;

   -- define producer task API (this example has no callable interface)
   task producer;

   task body producer is
   begin
      for I in 1 .. 30 loop
         buffer.write (I);
      end loop;
      buffer.proc_set_done;
      Put_Line("Producer done.");
   end producer;

   Next_Val : Integer;
begin

   -- The main procedure acts as the consumer in this example
   loop
      exit when buffer.proc_complete and then buffer.is_empty;
      buffer.read (Next_Val);
      Put_Line ("Consumer read" & Next_Val'Image);
      delay 0.001; -- slow down the consumer
   end loop;
   Put_Line ("Consumer done.");
end Main;
```

Ada protected objects are protected from race conditions. Protected objects are passive objects of concurrency called by tasks (similar to C++ threads). The methods of a protected object implicitly manipulate locks on their shared object.

Ada enforces a clear separation of specification (API) from implementation. The protected object specification is:

```ada
   protected buffer is
      entry write (value : in Integer);
      entry read (value : out Integer);
      procedure proc_set_done;
      function is_empty return Boolean;
      function proc_complete return Boolean;
   private
      Buff        : bounded_buffer;
      Write_Index : idx_t   := idx_t'First;
      Read_Index  : idx_t   := idx_t'First;
      Count       : Natural := 0;
      Complete    : Boolean := False;
   end buffer;
```

This protected object has five methods. Every protected entry has an associated condition variable. Protected procedures have no associated condition variable. Both protected entries and protected procedures implement an exclusive read-write lock on the protected object. Protected functions are read-only methods implementing a shared read-only lock on the protected object.

The private part of the protected object specification declares all the data members of the protected object. Those data members are only accessible to calling tasks through the entries, procedures and functions declared in the protected object specification.

The implementation of the protected methods is contained in the protected body.

```ada
-- Define the behavior of bounded_buffer
   protected body buffer is
      entry write (value : in Integer) when Count < Buff'Length is
      begin
         Buff (Write_Index) := value;
         Write_Index        := Write_Index + 1;
         Count              := Count + 1;
      end write;

      entry read (value : out Integer) when Count > 0 is
      begin
         value      := Buff (Read_Index);
         Read_Index := Read_Index + 1;
         Count      := Count - 1;
      end read;

      procedure proc_set_done is
      begin
         Complete := True;
      end proc_set_done;

      function is_empty return Boolean is
      begin
         return Count = 0;
      end is_empty;

      function proc_complete return Boolean is
      begin
         return Complete;
      end proc_complete;
   end buffer;
```

The index type chosen for the bounded_buffer array type is a modular type. Ada modular types exhibit modular arithmetic and work very well as an index to a circular buffer. In this case the modular type is:

```ada
type idx_t is mod 10;
```

The valid values for an instance of this type are 0 through 9 inclusive. Thus, the array type indexed by idx_t has a starting index value of 0 and an ending index value of 9. Adding 1 to 9 results in 0. Thus, the logic in the read and write entries simply increments the respective write_index or read_index with each operation.

The condition associated with the Write entry is "when Count < Buff'Length". Buff'Length evaluates to the number of elements in the Buff array.

The producer task specification is simple. This example has no direct interface to the producer task. The producer task simply writes to buffer.

The implementation of the producer task simply writes the values 1 through 30 to the buffer, calls buffer.proc_set_done, and outputs a message stating the producer is done.

The main procedure runs in the root task (or thread) for this program and is used as the consumer. The consumer simply iteratively loops through reading from buffer  until buffer.proc_complete is TRUE and also buffer.is_empty is TRUE. A delay statement is used in the consumer to slow it down so that the output clearly shows the producer completing well before the consumer without deadlocking the consumer.

The output of this program is:

```text
Consumer read 1
Consumer read 2
Consumer read 3
Consumer read 4
Consumer read 5
Consumer read 6
Consumer read 7
Consumer read 8
Consumer read 9
Consumer read 10
Consumer read 11
Consumer read 12
Consumer read 13
Consumer read 14
Consumer read 15
Consumer read 16
Consumer read 17
Consumer read 18
Consumer read 19
Consumer read 20
Producer done.
Consumer read 21
Consumer read 22
Consumer read 23
Consumer read 24
Consumer read 25
Consumer read 26
Consumer read 27
Consumer read 28
Consumer read 29
Consumer read 30
Consumer done.
```

Comment: The question is tagged with the [tag:c#] tag, not with the [tag:language-agnostic] tag.

Comment: It is also tagged with multithreading and producer-consumer. I have provided a producer-consumer solution which should be easily translated into C# or any other thread-capable language.

Comment: I can't understand this code. It is quite complicated. Not sure, if you can't translate this into C#. C# is way more easy than this language syntax.

Comment: My understanding is that an answer to a question with the [tag:c#] tag should include code only in C#, unless the OP has explicitly allowed the use of other languages.

Comment: The question has four tags. I do not follow the C# group but I do follow the multitasking and producer-consumer groups. Does that mean I am excluded from helping? The question did not ask how to achieve the author's goals in C#. It asked how to keep the consumer from deadlocking, which is a general multitasking and producer-consumer question.